# Excluding records from one table depending of other entries from same table

Tags: axapta, x++

I got following problem:

I have to correct a report in AX 4.0, which is created with the standard report-framework of AX and I don´t want to rework the whole report for this.

How can I set up the Datasources, so records from Table_A, which have the same Value in Field_A as **other** records from Table_A have in Field_B, are both not displayed anymore?

I´m driving crazy right now, because I haven´t found any solution for this, while it seems not that complicated.

Comment: what tables, what fields?

Answer (score 0):

You should work on the Query associated to the report datasource. But it's difficult to give a more accurate tip without knowing more information about the problem.